# 5th degree polynomial with positive leading coefficient

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, graphing-functions

[image]

I'm guessing C or D because odd degree polynomials which aren't linear extend one way to infinity and the other way to negative infinity?

So what's the relevance of the a>0? As x approaches infinity we should have infinity so the answer is C?

Comment: The image is inverted!

Comment: Yes your answer is correct.

Comment: @MaxPayne Thanks :)) Post as answer? Elaborate however you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is $C$. Btw, notice there's a '$3x$'. This is just a distraction. All we need to know to determine the answer is:

$1)$ The polynomial is $5th$ degree

$2)$ $a>0$

This tells us that as $x$ approaches $\infty$ $f(x)$ should approach $\infty$. As $x$ approaches  $-\infty$, $f(x)$ should approach $-\infty$. $C$ is the only choice that satisfies these requirements.

My favorite way of remembering the end behavior of polynomials is by just thinking about a line for an odd degree polynomial, and a quadratic for an even degree polynomial. The end behavior of both of these should already be very familiar to you. All functions of odd degree will have the same end behavior as lines (with the respective positive or negative leading coefficient) and functions of even degree will have the same behavior as parabolas.

Comment: Which is what I said. Have How is the 3x a distraction?

Comment: @BCLC Because $e=3$ is the only other concrete piece of information given (besides $5^{th}$ degree and $a>0$), but it has no use at all in helping us select the correct answer.

Comment: but who said anything about the 3x? I didn't even notice it

Comment: I just mentioned it for completeness